# deploy app to different iphone devices

Tags: iphone

I have 4 devices installed different ios version.
There are 5 usb interfaces on my mac.
Is it possible to deploy the ad hoc version to these devices for testing automatically?
I wonder if it needs apple script?

Welcome any comment

Comment: you can archive an ipa file with the UDID of all these devices and install it to them all through iTunes. And 5 usb slots! Which mac are you using?

Comment: The mac pro (Desktop) has 5 usb slots. its a nice developer box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transporter Chief is a ruby program that is written/intended to do exactly this.  Here's a blog post on setting it up and using it:

http://gamua.com/blog/2012/03/how-to-deploy-ios-apps-to-the-iphone-via-the-command-line/